Line of Sight angle/bearing calculations b/w ownship and target ship
My question is about Line of Sight (LoS) calculations.
Let us assume I have x,y,z coordinates of ownship and target (925,1.62e3,50) and (1.50e3,1.00e3,25) respectively. The ownship course is 300deg and target course is 45 deg. All angles are measured clockwise w.r.t True North. I need to calculate following:

Line of sight (LoS)
Angle on the bow (ATB)
Target Relative Bearing (TRB)
Relative speed across the line of sight (Xr)
Relative speed in the line of sight (Yr)

Help me in these calclations please.

This sounds like homework. Please share your work so far: what have you done and where exactly are you stuck? In any case, step #1: draw a picture

none of these are signal processing properties; this question is off-topic.
